# Unable to open Uibuilder (Node-red) on Rasberry pi

Tags: vue.js, node-red, bootstrap-vue, uibuilder

I have successfully installed Node-RED on Rasberry pi and I have also imported the flow needed for the system. But I'm unable to open Uibuilder since it shows an error of Vue and Bootstrap-vue files unavailable. I have also copied Vue.js and Bootstrap-vue.js files in the node modules folder of Rasberry pi (/home/pi/node_modules/) from my old processor where node-red use to run properly but still, it is unable to open Uibuilder.

[image: Uibuilder error message]

Answer (score 0):

My Node-RED had some nodes which were not present, due to which the Uibuilder URL was not able to be deployed. That's the reason it showed the error

Well, thanks anyway!!